# Creating a maven wrapper pom.xml from gradle: can't create the <build> element

Tags: gradle, pom.xml

How do I set the `sourceDirectory`, `testSourceDirectory` and build `plugins` in a pom.xml that I'm creating using the gradle maven-plugin's `pom` DSL?

When I add `build` without a `Closure` to my DSL section, it's ok.. but when I add `build { /* anything else, like actual compile plugins */}` it gives me this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':mavenWrapper'.
> No such property: _SCRIPT_CLASS_NAME_ for class: org.apache.maven.model.Model
```

I'm guessing that gradle is treating `build` as the task rather than the DSL verb generated by `org.sonatype.maven.polyglot.groovy.builder.ModelBuilder`.

Is there a way to force `build` to be treated as part of the DSL? Can it be cast or something?

Right now I'm working around this by using `.withXml` but it's massively verbose and much less maintainable.

Here's an abbreviated version of what I've got working:

```
task mavenWrapper {
    doLast {
        delete 'pom.xml', 'mvnw', 'mvnw.cmd'
        pom {
            project {
                packaging 'pom'
                repositories {
                    repository {
                        id 'spring-milestones'
                        name 'Spring Milestones'
                        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
                        snapshots {
                            enabled 'false'
                        }
                    }
                }
                properties {
                    'kotlin.compiler.incremental' 'true'
                }
                /* ******** Problem is here
                build {
                    plugins {
                        plugin {
                            // ... etc. etc.
                        }
                    }
                }
                ******* */
                dependencyManagement {
                    dependencies {
                        dependency {
                            groupId 'org.jetbrains.kotlin'
                            artifactId 'kotlin-stdlib-jre8'
                            version "${kotlin_version}"
                            scope 'compile'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.withXml {
           // Workaround for the missing build { ... } section above.
           asNode().appendNode('build').appendNode('plugins')
           // etc. etc.
        }.writeTo("${projectDir}/pom.xml")
        exec {
            commandLine 'mvn', '-N', 'io.takari:maven:wrapper', '-Dmaven=3.5.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've also tried `delegate.build`. No change.